# How to create a navigation property with a key that is not the the primary key of the 2nd object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, composite-key, fluent-interface

In EF5, using a code first approach and fluent API, how can create a navigation property (many to 1) based on a key that is not the primary key of the other table?

My database model is as such, and **I can't change it** :

- TableFoo1

  - Foo1ID int (key)
  - Field1 int
  - Value varchar
- TableFoo2

  - Foo2ID int (key)
  - Field1 int
  - Value varchar
- TableBar

  - BarID int (key)
  - Field1 int
  - Value varchar

I want my these entities :

```
public class Foo1
{
    public int Foo1ID { get; set; }
    public int BarID { get; set; }    //It corresponds Bar.ID
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2
{
    public int Foo2ID { get; set; }
    public int BarID { get; set; }    //It corresponds to Bar.Field1, NOT Bar.ID
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my maps (**the 2nd one is the incomplete one**) :

```
public  class Foo1Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo1>
{
    public Foo1Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Foo1ID);

        // Links to Bar's Primary Key, yay, it's easy.
        this.HasRequired(e => e.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.BarID);
    }
}

public  class Foo2Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo2>
{
    public Foo2Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Foo2ID);

        // No clues of how to links to Bar's other unique column, but not primary key.
        this.HasRequired(e => e.Bar).WithMany()........?
    }
}

public class BarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.BarID);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating entity relationship with renamed fields and non-primary key in primary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352114/creating-entity-relationship-with-renamed-fields-and-non-primary-key-in-primary)

Comment: I saw another post that said the same thing, but was older so I didn't know if it was EF5 or EF1. The one you linked clearly shows it's still current for EF5 (and will be for EF6.) Thanks, I'll close my question.

Comment: Also, I added an answer of a work around this issue that can work in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case I asked in the questions, where `Foo1` and `Foo2` both link to `Bar` with different keys (on the `Bar` side) can't be done in EF5 (more details in the post this question is an almost duplicate of) as is. However, if all your objects (`Foo1` and `Foo2` here) need to map on **the same** column (with a unicity constraint), even if it's not the PK of the other object (`Bar` here) in the mapping you can set that column to be the key. Also, if you do not want to use the same column for `Foo1` and `Foo2`, but you will never need `Foo1` and `Foo2` in the same instance of the context, you could use dynamic mapping, but it's dangerous and has a lot of complications.