# Add navigation property with non-primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

Here's my simplified scenario.

I have 2 db tables

```
Customer
Order
```

Both tables have the expected Id primary keys (CustomerId and OrderId).

A Customer can have multiple orders.

In the DB, there is no foreign keys configured and for a legacy reason, the Customer reference orders not by the OrderId field, but by another field called OrderRef

Forward onto EF and code first...

I have a Customer and Order POCO

I need something like the following...

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
    }
```

My question, is how can I tell EF to use the OrderRef field on the Orders table as the reference for the look up?

I realise that the DB design is bad - but it's not my DB, it's a legacy DB and it cannot be changed.

Comment: You will be probably out of luck: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15373090/270591

Comment: yep - seems to answer my question - thank you for your help