# EF 5 / One to Zero-or-One with Unique Constraint

Tags: entity-framework, unique-constraint

In my database I have three tables. TestVP, TestProject and TestPitch. The relationships are shown in this diagram. TestVP is the master table, TestProject and TestPitch when created a row is linked to TestVP. In EF World TestVP is 1 and the others 0..1.

http://tinypic.com/r/a3pg69/6

http://tinypic.com/r/ve69w/6

TestVP and TestPitch are linked with primary keys, so EF understands it correct and makes it 1 - 0..1.

TestVP and TestProject are linked with FK. ID <-> FKID and FKID is Unique. EF generates in this case a 1 - * association.

How can I change this in EF without changing database structure? I want to have 1 - 0..1 between TestVP and TestProject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework ignores unique key constraints (other than on the primary key) in the database and [they are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373090/270591). As a result one-to-one associations with foreign keys that are not identical with the primary key are not supported.

The best workaround is to not use a navigation property on the principal `TestVP` but only on the dependent `TestProject`. If your are using database-first remove the collection property in `TestVP` manually after EF created it.

For EF the relationship is still one-to-many but you are not at risk to add accidentally more then one entity to the collection (which would fail in the database due to the unique constraint).