# How to map composite foreign key to a non-primary unique key in FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need to map a legacy db that has composite foreign keys referring to non-primary unique keys.

First, I was trying to map it in EntityFramework. Unfortunately, I have found that EntityFramework (or at least 5.0) [does not support that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352114#15373090).

Now, I am trying to achieve that in NHibernate (with fluent mapping). However, I am unable to find any examples [in the docs](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping). Neither I have found that [among the unsupported features](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Current-NHibernate-Features-Not-Supported-In-Fluent).

Does NHibernate support that? Are there some samples or docs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CompositeId](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/krfWXrMGphM) method to create composite keys.

```
CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Property1).KeyProperty(x => x.Property2);
```

Comment: How to map then the foreign keys to particular composite ids? (The legacy tables has multiple composite unique keys in addition to the primary key.)

Comment: Can you post a simple example of what you need to do?